# Sharepoint Site using PHP code

Tags: sharepoint

I realise that Sharepoint in asp .net based but I have a PHP application that a user wants me to include in a Sharepoint site.

So is it possible to use PHP code inside sharepoint?

Comment: Seriously.. Users / clients are the weirdest of creatures around... =/

Comment: @Artiom No, we are. The Users / clients have nice buttons on app1 and new buttons on app2, should it take a full technology switch to use both things together? They make perfect sense to me, our broken IT world is to be blamed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

danit, when you say 'include' in the site, would it mean to be part of the site chrome (like inside the same menus etc) or just live connected with links would suffice?

I ask that because you can run php code under an IIS site but that would only keep the pages separated inside the same virtual host. if you need to actually join the functionalities you can:

1. Fake it with an iFrame (Page Viewer Web Part pointing to the php site for example).
2. you'll have to use some interop like webservices. It really comes down to what you want to do and not to if it is possible.

Comment: +1 for the "fake it with an [i]Frame". This makes my head spin -- I thought my SP clients were "interesting enough".

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible by creating a web part page and adding a page viewer web part.  You can link to the page, making it visible within the Sharepoint site, but it won't offer any interaction with Sharepoint itself.

Sharepoint treats the page as a shared document, however, so you can restrict access to it.  I have done this in order to offer access to 'view only' content such as reports, but you can also use it for custom php apps that rely on a database other than the one(s) Sharepoint is using.