# How to enable Sharepoint to get php files executed instead of downloaded?

Tags: php, sharepoint, iis-6

I've been struggling around with this issue for quite a few days now. We want to use Sharepoint as a repository of documents and code-files to show customers kind of dummy-webpages/applications or presentations of upcoming web projects using the integrated security and permission system.

PHP 5.3.4 is properly installed using FastCGI and works fine if I put a php file physically on the file system on the same server where Sharpoint Server 2007 is running.
Execute permissions are set to "Scripts and Executables" in the IIS Manager as well.

But as soon as the php file comes from the Sharepoint document library the file gets start the download dialog instead of displaying the according php file in the browser.

In the Document Library Setting of the according document library the Advanced Setting for the "Browser-enabled Documents" is set to "Display as a webpage".

Any ideas about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done as the document is being stored in the database and is not like a file being served from the IIS file system. Have you seen this post:

[Sharepoint Site using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701955/sharepoint-site-using-php-code)

Not sure if that might help you. You could also consider using a link list and a managed path on the SharePoint server to allow you to display them more easily. Unfortunately it would take a little more work than just uploading the PHP docs to a library - but might be easier in the end.

Comment: I also suppose it would be a security breach to enable executing code from user-uploaded files...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I think it would not be possible. In 2010 you actually have to jump through some hoops just to get plain HTML files stored in a doc library not to be downloaded. http://code-journey.com/2011/01/08/sharepoint-2010-download-file-instead-of-opening-in-browser-pdf-xml-html-etc-x-download-options-header-trouble/

Comment: Well,that's bad news. 

Of course I would have separated the customer upload section from the viewing section (where the php is stored) with different permission settings. 
It would have been great if we could use the simple upload via Sharepoint and Sharepoint Permission Management to let only specified persons aceess to the viewing section and the upload section as well. I tryed the steps listed for 2010 Version (http://nerdtastictips.blogspot.com/2010/08/sp2010-forces-users-to-save-pdfs.html) but they don't work for 2007 and I'm not sure if these steps will working in 2010 for my purposes.

Comment: I was also trying to figure out if your workaround with the managed paths would allow me to use the build in Permission Management, but I couldn't get this to work either.

I defined a managed path to a physically stored php file or directory where php files are stored. And then I didn't get the other steps to do. Could you explain your workaround a bit more specific please?
Appriciate your help

Comment: I did not understand that customers would be actively uploading the documents. That changes things a little. What sort of authentication are you using Windows based or forms?

Comment: Each customer will get a separate Active Directory User to get authenticated. So we can differentiate who can look at which data.
Each customer will have his own separated Upload Section (Doc Library - just for presentations, graphics, worksheets and docs, not for executable files like php) That of course is working out of the box.

Comment: And on the other hand there will be Document Lib for each customer, where just we will have permission to upload files for viewing purposes for the customer (each customer has only viewing rights for their viewing section). But sometimes there could be the need to use php to show some things.
Therefore it should be possible to get the browser to execute the php files from there. Of course we could upload the php files physically and handle the permissions there. But it would be a more sophisticated way to handle that all within SP.