# Inserting PHP into Sharepoint

Tags: php, html, sharepoint

I have created a 'Contact Us' form for a SharePoint for a group in work. I created this using HTML and have created a PHP script for the backend to send the form to my email address. How do I go about inserting this PHP into SharePoint so that this works? Below is the HTML and PHP code.

```
 <span style="color: #00cc99; font-size: 15pt;"><span style="color: #00cc99;">Contact Us if you&#39;re interested in volunteering&#160;with Social Innovation.&#160;</span></span></p>
<table width="450">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <label>Name *</label> </td>
         <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <label>Email Address *</label> </td>
         <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <label>Message *</label> </td>
         <td valign="top">
            <textarea maxlength="1000" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table> 
<p>&#160;</p>

    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW TO SUSANNAH
    $email_to = "example@email.co.uk";

    $email_subject = "Sharepoint Volunteer Enquiry";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

//thank you message 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sharepoint Site using PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701955/sharepoint-site-using-php-code)

I did it the same way like they suggest in this post using the Page Viewer WebPart.

But as this post is 5 years old, there might be a free php-viewer Webpart by now (as there is a HTML-Viewer)

Comment: If you are using SharePoint 2013 i would suggest implementing a provider hosted app. The only issue with this is, that you would have to implement a trust relation with your PHP Server and SharePoint.
But if you have managed this, then you could implement all kinds of SharePoint apps using PHP.